# Using webpack build, the content of the font file that is built is JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, html, css, webpack

This is the configuration file for my webpack production environment

```js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    module: {
        rules: [

            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                        options: {
                            publicPath: (resourcePath, context) => {
                                return path.relative(path.dirname(resourcePath), context) + "/assets/images/";
                            },
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                    }
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/i,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'url-loader',
                        options: {
                            limit: 8192,
                            name: '[name].[contenthash].[ext]',
                            outputPath: 'assets/images',
                            publicPath: '/assets/images',
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'url-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: '[name].[contenthash].[ext]',
                            outputPath: 'assets/fonts',
                            publicPath: '/assets/fonts',
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },

        ]
    },
    entry: {
        index: './src/pages/index/index.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../public/'),
        filename: '[name].[contenthash:8].js',
        publicPath: './',
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'index.html',
            template: './src/pages/index/index.html',
            chunks: ['index']
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: 'assets/css/[name].[contenthash:8].css',
        }),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin()
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/'),
        }
    },
};
```

I tried to use `url-loader` to handle the image and font files, I used `url()` in css to reference these files, but after the build, these files were not generated in `assets/image` and `assets/fonts` directories as expected, but directly in the root of the build directory, and the contents of the files were JavaScript code, the file extensions looked like normal files, but the file contents and the file extensions were completely different

For example, the contents of an svg file are
`export default "/assets/images/filname.hash.svg";`

Suppose its file name is `a.svg` and its path is `build/a.svg`,in the page, it is also directly through `./a.svg`, but the content of the file is `/assets/images/b.svg`, the browser can not be displayed properly.Normally, the browser should refer directly to `/assets/images/b.svg`, not this accidental product,why is this?

Answer (score 0):

My webpack version is webpack 5, but I'm looking at the documentation for webpack 4, which is wrong. In webpack 5, there's no need to use `url-loader` or `file-loader` anymore, in webpack 5, files should be handled in this way

```
module.exports = {
  ...
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
                type: 'asset/resource',
                generator: {
                    filename: 'assets/images/[hash][ext][query]'
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/i,
                type: 'asset/resource',
                generator: {
                    filename: 'assets/fonts/[hash][ext][query]'
                }
            },
}
```